# хочу()хочу()хочу,

Tags: орфография

как написать хочу()хочу()хочу, ставить между словами дефис?

Comment: А в каком контексте может быть такое повторение? Представить что-то не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы допустил дефисы как авторское написание для передачи особенностей речи героя. 
Основным сводом правил такой вариант не предусмотрен.

Подробности - в остальных ответах.

Answer (score 0):

Повторяющиеся слова разделяются, как и однородные, запятыми.Дефис может стоять между ними, если это название чего-то.Если это шуточный диалог,можно и без запятых, но с новой строки каждое слово, как в песне"Я серого хочу":

Хочу

Хочу

Хочу

Я серого хочу...

А если других условий нет, то по правилу повторяющихся слов - через запятую:

хочу, хочу, хочу...

Comment: Слова разделяются запятыми... И точками ... И пробелы забывать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Правила правописания регламентируют написания сочетаний-повторов двух слов. Повторение больше двух слов входит в разряд однородных членов предложения и разделяются запятой.

Answer (score 0):

1) Лучше поставить запятые, интонация перечислительная:

Я как в детстве заклинание В небо глядя прошепчу: Чтоб исполнилось желание
Я хочу, хочу, хочу!!!Я хочу, хочу, хочу!!!

Шоколадный блинный тортик "Хочу, хочу!"

2) Дефис возможен при наличии двух слов, произношение без паузы:

Кондитерская "ХОЧУ-ХОЧУ".

Comment: Что за смысл ставить запятые между "хочу", когда во всём остальном "В небо глядя" пунктуация совершенно случайная?

Comment: Попробуем исправить, не нарушая авторскую мысль:  Я, как в детстве заклинание, В небо глядя,  прошепчу, Чтоб исполнилось желание: Я хочу, хочу, хочу!!!Я хочу, хочу, хочу!!!

Comment: По-моему, это ближе к правде.  Три восклицательных знака?????

Comment: Надо у slava спросить, сколько восклицательных и вопросительных знаков можно ставить. Может быть, их тоже "сколько угодно".

Answer (score 0):

> как написать хочу хочу хочу, ставить между словами дефис?

Всё зависит от контекста и интонации. А вариантов -- сколько угодно:

*Хочу... Хочу... Хочу...*

*И я хочу... хочу-хочу-хочу... съесть тебя...*

*Я хочу! Хочу-хочу!*

*Да, хочу. Хочу, хочу, хочу!*

*Я хочу... хочу... хочу!!!*

*Я тебя хочу! Хочу-хочу-хочу-хочу!*

*...*

Произносите без паузы -- ставьте дефис. Как в этом примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пять "хочу" можно произнести без паузы?

Comment: Слава, а почему Вы считаете, что в этом примере правильно поставлен дефис? Не все то правильно, что в встречается в интернете.

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что неправильно? И если бы название с тремя "хочу" имела б, к примеру,  какая-то кондитерская (в примере от Веры -- только два "хочу"), Вы бы что, предложили б заменить дефисы на запятые?

Comment: Дефисы указывают на интенсивность признака. а между повторяющимися словами ставится запятая, если обозначается высокая степень признака, качества, чувства, причем каждое из повторяющихся в таком случае слов имеет логическое ударение. (Лопатин)При дефисе отсутствует пауза, а при запятой - есть.  В приведенном примере трудно произнести слова без паузы.

Comment: _Серж: В приведенном примере трудно произнести слова без паузы._ === Кому трудно -- может воспользоваться запятыми. Ну а кто захочет произнести без пауз, поставит дефис.